# Number of conjugates of an $m$-cycle $\sigma$ in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-groups

I am currently reading the following from Dummit and Foote can someone explain to me why the number of conjugates of $\sigma$ is:

$$\frac{n(n\ -\ 1)...(n\ -\ m\ + \ 1)}{m}\ ?$$

Comment: But what is $m$ ?

Comment: Two permutations are conjugate iff they have the same cycle type, so you're just counting the number of $m$-cycles in $S_n$. If you write out an $m$-cycle, there are $n$ choices for the first spot, $n-1$ for the second etc. But then you have to divide by $m$ to account for cyclic permutations, since it doesn't matter what the first entry of the cycle is, just the order in which the entries are written, up to cyclic permutation, e.g. $(213)=(321)=(132)$.

Comment: Okay that is great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote
$$
\sigma=(a_{1}a_{2}\ldots a_{m})
$$
There is a theorem that states that for every $\tau\in S_{n}$ 
$$
\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau=(\tau(a_{1}),\tau(a_{2}),\ldots,\tau(a_{m}))
$$

thus, given any $m$ elements of $\{1,...,n\}$ there is some $\tau$
s.t $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$ will result in a cycle of those exactly
$m$ elements.

For the above formula recall two things:

1. $\binom{n}{m}$ is the number of ways choosing $m$ elements from
   a set of $n$ elements
2. Any cyclic shift of the $m$ elements results in the same cycle
   e.g $(123)=(231)=(312)$ so to cancel those repetitions we need to
   divide by $m$ which is the number of such cyclic shifts

Answer (score 4):

Two permutations in $S_{n}$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type, so really the question is how many $m$-cycles there are in $S_{n}$. Well, choose your $m$ elements from $n$ in $n\choose{m}$ ways. But we can rearrange those $m$ elements in $m!$ ways. Finally, each of our cycles has been represented $m$ times by a cyclic rearrangement, so we divide by $m$. So our final count is $$\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m}$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

A permutation is  conjugate if it has the same cycle structure. 
In this case you want to find the no. conjugates of a m cycle, so your question boils down to find the no. of m cycles in Sn.
Which can be done by n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1)/m ways as for first entry you have n options, for next entry you have (n-1) options and finally you divide n(n-1)...(n-m+1) by m as each m cycle can be represented in m ways.

Answer (score -1):

The number of combinations of $n$ distinct things taken $m$ at a time is your starting point, for which the binomial coefficient comes in handy: $n!/m!(n-m)!$ Since each combination will represent more than just one $m$-cycle, for every choice of the 1st spot of an $m$-cycle there will be $m-1$ choices for the 2nd spot, $m-2$ choices for the 3rd spot, etc. You then arrive at $(m-1)! \times n!/m!(n-m)!$

Comment: (m-1)! X n!/m!(n-m)! = n(n-1)...(n-m+1)/m is correct. You must multiply the binomial coefficient by (m-1)! to arrive m in the denominator. Each m-combination entails more than 1 m-cycle which accounts for the necessary adjustment to the binomial coeeficient.